# NSPredicate execureFetchRequest not working - possibly due to spaces in string

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, executefetchrequest

I am trying to search in CoreData for an object that matches both a recordId and a string name, but it doesn't always find the object.
For example, I an searching for an object with id 1000 and name "The  Brown Family" (note the 2 spaces between "The" and "Brown").
If I use:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(recordId == %@") AND (name like[cd] %@)", recordId, name];
```

with recordId=1000 and name="The  Brown Family", the fetch request returns nil.
If I use:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(recordId == %@"),   recordId];
```

with recordId=1000, it finds the object. If I print the object's name property, I get "The  Brown Family".
So the object is there with the correct id and name, but my fetchRequest fails.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to format your question properly (using the tags for code)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use `LIKE` and not `==` ?

Comment: I think I wrote it that way thinking that it would accept names with spaces between words, and that if the recordId matched, then that would be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to enclose the value in single quotes...

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(recordId == %@) AND (name like[cd] '%@')", recordId, name];
```

Comment: I tried that but it made no difference. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I looked through my results again. There are hundreds of names stored. The ones that I had spotted with problems before had double spaces etc. in the name string. However, looking through them again, I can see ones as simple as "Toby". So the spaces part is a red herring I think.

Comment: Silly question if you know the unique `recordId` (I assume its unique), why are you matching on name as well?

Comment: Usually the recordId would be enough. But there are occasions where the recordId changes e,g, going from device to device.

Comment: `name like[cd] '%@'` is wrong, that will search only for the verbatim string `"%@"`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I realise what the problem is now! The name I was searching for had a trailing space after it. So I was looking for say "Toby " whereas "Toby" was stored in Coredata.
Sorry for wasting everyone's time.