# NSFetchedResultsController fetchRequest for one-many relationship

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I would really appreciate some help with using `NSFetchResultsController`. 
I think what I am need to do should be simple for some people, but I am a bit stuck!

I will try to explain what I am doing, or a simplified version of it.
I have 2 viewControllers, each displaying an NSTableView. I am using Core Data, with an entity Clubs. One of the viewControllers displays a list of Clubs. So for this one, I create an `NSFetchResultsController`, passing to it a `fetchRequest` which is basically `NSFetchRequest<Clubs>(entityName: “Clubs”)`.

Each club has a list of Members, with a one-many relationship). I want to display the members using the 2nd viewController. So when I tap a club in the first table, I want the second table to show its members.

I have an `NSFetchResultsController` connected to the second table. I am stuck at what fetchRequest to send to it. If I use a similar one to the first, i.e. `NSFetchRequest<Members>(entityName: “Members”)`, as expected, I end up with one table showing all of the clubs stored, and the second table showing ALL members stored, whereas I want only the members in the club selected in the first table. I hope that makes sense. So my question is, what `fetchRequest` should I send to the 2nd tables `NSFetchResultsController`?

Comment: [Apperently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34633764/1187415) you know about *predicates* which can be assigned to a Core Data fetch request. Can you think of a predicate which restricts the members in the second view controller to the ones related to the club in the first view controller?

Comment: I know a little about predicates, but not enough to know which to use in this case.

Comment: Hi @MartinR - that is what I am asking - which predicate should I use??

Comment: @guinnessman What is the name of the inverse relationship - from `Member` to `Club`?

Comment: The Club has a relationship called members  - a one-tomany relation. Going from member to Club, is the relationship club.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the following predicate to the fetch request underlying the FRC:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"club == %@", theClubSelectedInTheFirstViewController)
```

Comment: Ok - I'll try that. In that example, is theClubSelectedInTheFirstViewController a Club entity (not a String)?

Comment: Yes, exactly: the Club entity itself, not a string.

Comment: That makes sense - thanks. I have tried it, and unfortunately it didn't work (I'm still getting all of the members rather that just for the selected Club) but I must have made a mistake somewhere. I will look into this fully tomorrow. Just wanted to thank you now for your help.

Comment: I think I have it working now. Perhaps this is obvious?? but in the place where I detect the Club getting selected, and where I change the predicate as per your instruction, I also had to do a new fetch:
 do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print ("Fetching error: \(error) \(error.userInfo)")
        }

Comment: Yes - I assumed you were setting the predicate before even initialising the FRC.  But if not, then you will need to redo the `performFetch` after updating the predicate.

Comment: The predicate was set prior to initialising the FRC, but the predicate does need to change each time the club is changed. Thanks again for your help :)